# LookupError: unknown encoding: idna - only from subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, ironpython

Im trying to invoke a python 2.7 script from an Iron python one using `subprocess.call`.
the invoked process uses imports that are not supported in IronPython like `scikit-learn` and `requests`.

Currently im trying to invoke the python 2.7 script using this comand:

```
sub_ret_val = subprocess.call("C:/Documents and Settings/avishay/workspace/BursaProject_V1_31/brainManager_toFile.py", shell = True, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but im getting:

> LookupError: unknown encoding: idna

now, this script works fine if I run it from the windows shell, or from eclipse pydev environment. what is the difference between running it from the shell, to running it from `subprocess.call` causing it to fail??

Thanks

---EDIT---

It seems I cant import encodings.idna either :

> ImportError: No module named idna

which is very very weird... 
printing `sys.path` shows that `c:\\Python27\\Lib` is there, and the idna.py file is in the encodings directory... how can the import not work???

---ONE MORE EDIT---

Ive found one way around the problem - starting the IronPython script from a python shell - and everything works fine. I still have no Idea why invoking the python 2.7 interpreter from IronPython interferes with python 2.7 internal modules... the PYTHONPATH does include the path to those modules, so I would very much appreciate any insight to what is happening under the hood.

Comment: create a complete minimal code example that shows the problem and post the full traceback e.g., put `print u'abc'.encode('idna')` into `child.py` file and call it from `parent.py`: `import subprocess; subprocess.call([r'c:\Python27\python.exe', 'child.py'])`. First run `parent.py` using CPython (to make sure that it works as expected) then run `parent.py` using IronPython and see whether it reproduces the problem.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I cannot reproduce the error the way you suggested. It works just fine when running `parent.py` with IronPython...

Comment: It means that CPython 2.7 finds "idna" encoding just fine. What happens if you call brainManager_toFile.py from parent.py instead of child.py?

Comment: hm... works as well. it seems the only problem is when running it from eclipse. still not sure why, but im going to let it go.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IronPython doesn't support `idna` encoding](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/4565) that is probably [used by `requests` module](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/555).

[`idna` encoding is available since Python 2.3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.idna):

```
>>> u"яндекс.рф".encode('idna')
b'xn--d1acpjx3f.xn--p1ai'
>>> b'xn--d1acpjx3f.xn--p1ai'.decode('idna')
'яндекс.рф'
```

To avoid ambiguity about what python is used to run your script, try specify the path to Python executable explicitly:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output as qx

output = qx([r"c:\Python27\python.exe", r"c:\path\to\script.py"], stderr=STDOUT)
```

As an alternative you could install [`pylauncher`](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher), to be able to specify a desired Python version for a Python script in its shebang line e.g., `#!python2.7`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried to specify explicitly the executable, but to no avail. I cant see why running from IronPython should make python 2.7 not find idna inside its `/Lib/encodings` folder..